# How we create our own $\pi$ finder formula/function?

Tags: functions, pi

1) Nilakantha Somayaji;

$\pi=3+\dfrac{4}{3^3-3}-\dfrac{4}{5^3-5}+\dfrac{4}{7^3-7}-\dfrac{4}{9^3-9}+.....$

2)Franciscus Vieta;

$\pi=2.\dfrac{2}{\sqrt2}.\dfrac{2}{\sqrt{2+\sqrt2}}.\dfrac{2}{\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt2}}}.\dfrac{2}{\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt2}}}}.....$

3)Gregory-Leibniz;

$\pi=\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}$

4)Isaac Newton
$\pi=\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{2^{(n+1)}.(n!)^2}{(2n+1)!}$

5)

6)

$\vdots$

This formulas ,from where come? How they did successfully finder formula of $\pi$

Can we create like these formulas?

I know ,my english not well,I hope I can explain myself.respects...

Comment: I think Gregroy-Leibniz should be equal $\pi/4$ and not $\pi$. This one is derived by using the taylor expansion of the $\arctan x$. Vietas formula is just a result from geometrical reasoning for the perimeter of a circle.

Comment: Even I couldn't understand :) .Thank you for informations.

Comment: The Somayaji formula reduces to the Gregory-Leibniz because $4/(n^3-n)=2/(n-1)-4/n+2/(n+1)$

Comment: You can find a collection of formulas and historical reference on http://pi314.net/eng/histoire.php

Comment: @Michael But Nilakantha's formula is a direct proof that $\pi>3$ and can be rewritten in positive terms only as
$$\pi=3+\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{24}{(4k+2)(4k+3)(4k+5)(4k+6)}$$
while from Gregory-Leibniz we get 
$$\pi=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{8}{(4k+1)(4k+3)}$$
and only $\pi>0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Precious Nilakantha's formula! In general from $f(x)$ if you have some value for which $af(x_0)=\pi$ you can developpe $f(x)$ in  series and you get a formula
$$\pi=a\sum a_nx_0^n$$ This general viewpoint could give some troubles, in particular the value of $x_0$ could be not good, the series cannot be convergent or not useful because convergence very slow (this occurs for example with Gregory-Leibniz's formula). The first in obtaining fast convergence was Machin putting the angle $\frac {\pi}{4}$ in function of smaller angles; he discovered in 1706 the formula $$\frac {\pi}{4}=4\arctan(\frac 15)-\arctan(\frac{1}{239})$$ in which with the values $x=\frac 15$ and $x=\frac{1}{239}$ give for the formula of Gregory an algorithm of fast convergence obtaining this way $100$ correct first digits for $\pi$.